# android get count total rows?

Tags: android, sqlite

I will appreciate if someone help me with this code below:

i'm trying to get total rows in my table: i'm calling from the button but it always crash...

```
public int countjournals() {
        Cursor dataCount = CountryDB.rawQuery("select count(*) from" + TABLE_NAME, null);
        dataCount.moveToFirst();
        int jcount = dataCount.getInt(0);
        dataCount.close();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Total:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return jcount;
    }
```

I have created it method in CountyDB like this:

```
 public static Cursor rawQuery(String string, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: post your logcat errors

Comment: You rawQuery returns null. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to either implement your `rawQuery()` or remove it. What you want is `SQLiteDatabase`'s `rawQuery()`.

Also, you need space between `from` and table name here:

```
"select count(*) from" + TABLE_NAME
```

change to:

```
"select count(*) from " + TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method rawQuery(String, String[]) from the type SQLiteDatabase

Comment: Call it on a database object, e.g. `dbhelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(...)`

Comment: And what does "doesn't work" mean? If there's a crash, post the logcat stacktrace in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it should work if not....
rawQuery method is returning null every time it seems once check with that

```
 public static Cursor rawQuery(String string, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private int getCount(){
            int count = 0;
            String query = "SELECT * FROM "+"Table_Name";
            Cursor cursor = CountryDB.rawQuery(query, null);

            while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                    int x = cursor.getInt(0);
                    Log.e("", "x = "+x);
                    count++;
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }

            cursor.close();
            CountryDB.close();

            return count;
        }
```

Make sure that database object is not null and your table is created first and column data type is integer . If you are putting string data then use `getString(0);`

this code is working fine for me.